# OSX Sleep mode messes with sound and window sizes

Tags: macos, audio, sleep

Here is my work environment:

- 13" Retina Macbook Pro 2015 (The Force Touch thing)
- Latest OSX
- External DELL Screen connected with HDMI (set as the main screen)
- Apple Earbuds connected to the rMBPs headphone jack
- Bluetooth Apple Keyboard and Magic Mouse

When I'm not at my desk I want to lock my computer similar to `WIN+L` on Windows. The only solution I found was to put my Mac to sleep with `CTRL+SHIFT+EJECT/POWER` - I also do this each evening.

My problem is when the mac wakes up again:

- All Windows on my DELL screen are resized. They're smaller and I have to resize every single one again.
- Sound doesn't work anymore. Pressing the volume keys shows the crossed out circle below the speaker image. This is fixed by unplugging and re-plugging the headphones.

It's really an annoying problem. Is there any way OSX keeps my windows and sound stuff when waking up from sleep?

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem here and it doesn't seem to be well catalogued on the internet! In general it seems Macs have rubbish reliability on headphone jacks and now this bug as well! No wonder they want to eliminate the port altogether!

Solution: A manual sleep and wake up seems to correct the sound issue for me. I've now disabled automatic sleep in System Preferences as it's buggy.

P.S. This looks to be a hardware bug as it effects El Capitan and Mountain Lion at least.

Comment: You say, ‘‘A manual sleep and wake up seems to correct the sound issue for me.’’  How is this different from what the OP is already doing?